# Select total and full total on one line

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Table X

| AccountId | InvoiceId | SeasonId | AmountSold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I1 | S1 | 5 |
| 1 | I1 | S1 | 5 |
| 1 | I1 | S2 | 6 |
| 1 | I2 | S1 | 8 |

I need this; filter on AccountId = 1, Group By SeasonId (no problem) but also the "Full Total Per InvoiceId"

| AccountId | InvoiceId | SeasonId | AmountSold | TotalInvoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I1 | S1 | 10 | 16 |
| 1 | I1 | S2 | 6 | 16 |
| 1 | I2 | S2 | 8 | 8 |

Comment: Use a windowed `SUM`.

Comment: I never used Windowed SUM.. Can you give the query for this specific example please?

Comment: [SUM (Transact-SQL) - Using the OVER clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#b-using-the-over-clause)

Comment: ok, looks like a good example, I'll look into it later on, thanks!

Comment: Craft your solution from that link, try to make it working. Then publish your solution by updating your post (if it doesn't work) or in the answers section (if you manage to carry it out correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate by acount/invoice/season first, then use window functions to compute the grand total per invoice:

```
select accountId, invoiceId, seasonId, 
    sum(amountSold) amountSold,
    sum(sum(amountSold)) over(partition by accountId, invoiceId) totalInvoice
from mytable
group by accountId, invoiceId, seasonId
```

Of course if you want to filter on a given account id, we can use a `where` clause (and then it its not needed anymore to group and partition by that):

```
select invoiceId, seasonId, 
    sum(amountSold) amountSold,
    sum(sum(amountSold)) over(partition by invoiceId) totalInvoice
from mytable
where accountId = 1
group by invoiceId, seasonId
```

Comment: Thank you for your input; I'm on holidays now, I'll look into it next week